# Is this natural abstraction principle consistent with ZF?

Tags: logic, set-theory

This is a question about equivalence of distinct implementations of mathematical concepts in set theory.

We call a line of definitions of all the primitives of arithemtic $N, =, <, 0, S, + , \times$ in the language of set theory in such a manner that all axioms of Peano arithmetic are provable in ZFC when written in terms of the definitions belonging to that line, and provided that all quantifiers restricted to the set standing for $N$, now call such a line as "arithemtic defining line".

Is the following prinicple consistent with ZF?

**Natural absraction principle:** if line 1 and line 2 are distinct arithmetic defining lines, then if $\phi^1$ is a formula in the defined language of arithmetic along line 1, and if $\phi^2$ is the same formula but after definition line 2, then $$\phi^1 \iff \phi^2$$

If it is consistent, then would adding it to ZF increase the consistency strength of ZF?

Comment: What is a line in this context?

Comment: A set of definitions of the primitives of arithmetic

Comment: In what language?

Comment: the language of set theory, that is first order logic with identity and membership

Comment: ZF is strong enough to formalize a line, so adding this principle does not make it stronger.

Comment: @user953376 AC is only needed for completeness when the languages of the theories in question are not assumed to be well-orderable. Since the language of arithmetic is finite, this isn't an issue. Indeed the relevant form of completeness is already provable in very weak theories (namely $\mathsf{WKL_0}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing like the abstraction principle you describe can be consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$, or indeed much less.

In $\mathsf{ZF}$, every definable consistent theory in a finite language has a definable model. More precisely, for every formula $\varphi$ there is some formula $\psi$ such that $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves "If $\varphi$ defines a consistent theory in a finite language then $\psi$ defines a model of that theory." This is simply a consequence of the definability of the construction in the Henkinization proof of the completeness theorem. *(The axiom of choice is often mentioned in the context of the completeness theorem, but only when non-well-orderable languages are considered.)*

In particular, there are formulas $\theta,\eta$ which $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves define models of $\mathsf{PA+Con(PA)}$ and $\mathsf{PA+\neg Con(PA)}$ respectively.

---

EDIT: alternatively, consider "the $L$-least model of $\mathsf{PA}$" versus "the $L$-least model of $\mathsf{PA}$ *not elementarily equivalent to* the $L$-least model of $\mathsf{PA}$." Or etc. There are lots of tools in $\mathsf{ZF}$ for explicitly defining non-elementarily-equivalent models of $\mathsf{PA}$.

Comment: You said "much less". How much less?

Comment: @Zuhair Already $\mathsf{WKL_0}$ can prove the completeness theorem.